# disk check PowerShell with report

Tags: powershell, disk

I made a PowerShell script to write a report and highlight any disk under 20% of space but the script keeps failing because the size value is not right. Can you please help me?

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\gbekari\unbackup\Servers.txt

$results = foreach ($Computer in $Computers){
    Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='3'" -ComputerName $Computer | ForEach {
           New-Object PSObject -Property @{

           Computername = $computer
           date         = (Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yy HH:mm")
           size         = ([Math]::Round($_.Size /1GB,2))
           freeSpace    = ([Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace /1GB,2))
           Status       = if ([Math]::Round(100 * $db.FreeSpace / $db.Size) -gt 19 ) {'NONE'} else {'Warning'}
           empty        = "Diskcheck"
           }
        }
}

$results | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|" | % {$_-replace'"',''} | Set-Content -Path C:\Users\gbekari\unbackup\Sers.txt
```

Comment: To improve this question you should explain what "the size value is not [right]" means, however I can tell you that the `Win32_Volume` class doesn't have a `Size` property; try changing it to `Capacity`.  Also, when computing the `Status` property you start using a `$db` variable — which isn't defined anywhere inside that loop — instead of `$_`.

Comment: sorry for the poor explanation as not right I meant the the value is zero and the status value fail because can divide by 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lance U. Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150605/lance-u-matthews) is on point with his comment, you're trying to reference a property (`Size`) that does not exist in the [**Win32_Volume Class**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa394515(v=vs.85)) and you're referencing a variable that is not defined (`$db`).

As aside, if you're running **PowerShell 3.0 or above**, you can construct objects by casting [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.2) instead of using [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-7.2), this way is more direct and efficient.

[`Get-WmiObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) does not longer exist in newer versions of PowerShell and as stated in the docs:

> Starting in PowerShell 3.0, this cmdlet has been superseded by [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.2)

You can also query all computers in parallel, `-ComputerName` accepts an array of computers.

```bash
$Computers = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\gbekari\unbackup\Servers.txt
$results = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType='3'" -ComputerName $Computers | ForEach-Object {
    $status = if ([Math]::Round(100 * $_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity) -gt 19 ) {
        'NONE'
    }
    else {
        'Warning'
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Date         = Get-Date -format "dd.MM.yy HH:mm"
        Size         = [Math]::Round($_.Capacity / 1GB, 2)
        FreeSpace    = [Math]::Round($_.FreeSpace / 1GB, 2)
        Status       = $status
        Empty        = "Diskcheck"
    }
}

($results | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|") -replace '"', '' |
    Set-Content -Path C:\Users\gbekari\unbackup\Sers.txt
```

If you don't mind having the computer names in a column named `PSComputerName`, leave the code as-is, if instead you want to change the column name you can use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
($results | Select-Object @{N='ComputerName'; E={ $_.PSComputerName }}, * |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|") -replace '"', '' |
        Set-Content -Path C:\Users\gbekari\unbackup\Sers.txt
```